# Doubt in Pedigree chart : why can't the attached pic be autosomal recessive?

Tags: pedigree

[image]

Why is the attached Pedigree chart can't be called as autosomal recessive also?

[image]

Comment: Pretty similar to this one: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/114172/27148

Comment: But in there they speak about 2 families, And it's more detailed. My question is simple.

Comment: Not really, it's exactly the same. What assumptions need to happen exactly out of the things unknown for this pedigree to result from an autosomal recessive trait? What assumptions are necessary for it to result from an X-linked trait?

Comment: The premise of your question is wrong. This pedigree _can_ very well be explained also with the autosomal recessive inheritance, and there is no way of knowing whether it is autosomal recessive or X-linked recessive purely from this pedigree.

Comment: Indian English “doubt” does not work in International English, and is not generally understood. Use “question” or “problem”.

Comment: @domen can't we decide by writing and seeing out the possibile genotype and finding out the progeny. If I am wrong ,can you correct my ideology?

Comment: @david can you say in which part you can't understand the question? I can clarify 

Comment: I am not interested in the science of your question, I am only trying to help you communicate it in International English. I have suggested words to replace it and suggest you consult an online dictionary such as Merriam-Webster that will give examples of usage of "doubt": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doubt.

Comment: @SanjayS, try it yourself! Write down the genotypes, and you will find out that the pedigree can be explained by either of the two aforementioned inheritance patterns.

Comment: @domen yeah doman I have done that , and let me attach my image in the question

Comment: Great, you've find one possible set of genotypes (not the only one though) which is compatible with the hypothesis that the inheritance is autosomal recessive. So you've answered the question yourself :)

Comment: According to me this chart applicable for both autosomal recessive and x linked recessive. I just wanna confirm you guys whether this is correct or not?

Comment: Yes, but consider what initial unknowns have to be for that to be the case and how reasonable/likely that is. In this case your autosomal recessive chart only works if the two unknowns (numbered 2 and 3) happen to be carriers. If carriers are rare in the population, that might not be reasonable.

Comment: Ok Bryan thanks for your reply 